# Mock AsyncTask onPostExecute()

Tags: android, functional-testing, android-testing

i need to `mock/stub` the `AsyncTask` `doInBackground(String... params)` during Android's functional test. It has a `HTTP Post` that receive a `JSON` if everything on the server goes right and pass it casted to String in `onPostExecute`.
So, if static method calls the `AsyncTask` that save a `SharedPreferences` made with `HTTP Post` response's data, I want to test if this data is stored in `SharedPreferenced`, but i need to mock `URL` call because I've not already developed the server side.

Comment: You can use the JSON-Server tool to create a fake backend that just returns the json you gave it. You just write your json and connect to this url  instead of your original and you're done. Hope it can help you. Link: https://github.com/typicode/json-server

Answer (score 1):

How about subclassing AsyncTask? You can Make AsyncTaskMock class and then inherit doInBackground(String... params) to do Whatever you want. Also you can send a debug flag in the intent of the activity, and if it is set you can make if else: if it is debug use the AsyncTaskMock and if not use the regular.

Comment: Nice idea, have you some guides to achieve It? I'm new to testsuite